# jquery go to page without animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have jquery code like this :

```
var pageWidth = 230;
var sliderStartPosition = 0;
var sliderPageWidth = pageWidth;

function goToPage(slideNum){
    var offset = (slideNum-1) * sliderPageWidth;
    $('#js_slides').animate({left:'-'+offset+'px'}, 500, function(){
        $('#js_slides li').each(function(){ this.scrollTop = 0; });
    });
    return false;

}

function goToPageWithoutAnimation(slideNum){
    var offset = (slideNum-1) * sliderPageWidth;
    //code here
}
```

This is the css :

```
div.sliderContainer {
    width: 230px; /*width of one page to slide*/
    overflow: hidden;
}

div.sliderContainer ul {
    position: relative;
    width: 690px;
    list-style: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

div.sliderContainer ul li{
    float: left;
    width: 210px;
    height: 380px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

i need your help, how go to page without animation.
please help me.

Comment: You'll need to post the HTML and an example such as jsFiddle would be helpful.

Comment: If you reduce the animation time (currently = 500ms) to ZERO does that produce the result you want to see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `animate` with `css`:

```
$('#js_slides').css({left:'-'+offset+'px'});
$('#js_slides li').each(function(){ this.scrollTop = 0; });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `css` instead of `animate`:

```
$('#js_slides').css({left:'-'+offset+'px'});
$('#js_slides li').each(function(){ this.scrollTop = 0; });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve the code you have (rather than adopting an alternate approach) then you could reduce the animation time (currently = 500ms) to ZERO which will produce the result you want to see.

Like this:

```
 $('#js_slides').animate({left:'-'+offset+'px'}, 0, function(){
        $('#js_slides li').each(function(){ this.scrollTop = 0; });
    });
```